# Do I need a visa to study abroad in the Czech Republic? More details inside

Tags: visas, us-citizens, czech-republic

I got into a study abroad program through my university (University of Washington, located in Seattle,Washington) that takes place in the Czech republic for a period of 71 days, from March 26,2016 to June 4,2016. What makes this more complicated is that I was in Latvia over Winter Break from December 16, 2015 til January 10, 2016, which is 26 days. I understand that you cannot be over 90 days in a given 180 days.

I am also based in Seattle, WA so in the occurrence I need a short-term visa, do I need to go to the Consulate in San Francisco or Los Angeles, since I need to be in person to submit my fingerprints?

Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: Your fingerprints should be on file in the Schengen database. Check if they *really* want new ones.

Comment: A (new) short term visa is not an option. Short term visas are valid for at most 90 days within a 180 days period and a new visa does not reset the 'day counter' from previous visits. Assuming that you are a US citizen, you would not even get a short term visa, since you are eligible for visa-free short term visits.

Answer (score 2):

Your question as to where to apply (LA) is answered on the Czech Embassy website: http://www.mzv.cz/washington/en/consular_information/contacts/offices_in_usa.html

Your question about length of stay would be best answered by calling the same consulate you would apply at.  They would know best what visa you need (if any) and what supporting documents you will need.  And pray they don't tell you to get a student visa as that can take two months to be issued. :(

Comment: Why do you think he'll get through with anything but a study visa? Long term visas for other purposes are btw not a better option. They can take 90 days to be issued.

Comment: I don't know exactly how they will treat this hence why I said "call them".  I mentioned the time frame simply because he is traveling in about 60 days and the Czech website mentioned 60 to 90 days.